# getting folders in one string

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a batch script to loop through folders and subfolders, and return all folders that contain xml files in a single string. (I need to be able to send this as a parameter)

My folder structure is relatively simple, I have a 'parent' folder, containing subfolders, and each of these contain xml files. So folder structure looks as follows :

MasterFolder1 > Subfolder1 > file1.xml - file2.xml ... more files
                           Subfolder2 > file1.xml - file2.xml ... more files
                          ... more subfolders

MasterFolder2 > Subfolder1 > file1.xml - file2.xml ... more files
                           Subfolder2 > file1.xml - file2.xml ... more files
                          ... more subfolders

and so on

What I was already able to construct is the batch data that will loop through all the folders, and only cares about the ones with xml files. It looks as follows :

```
@echo off & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion

set catdir=%CD%\catalog\%
cd %catdir%

FOR /f %%G in ('dir /ad/s/b') DO (
if exist %%G\*.xml ( 

for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=\/" %%i in ("%%G") do (
set model=%%m   REM 'model' is the master folder name
set locale=%%n  REM 'locale' is the sub folder name

echo %%m - %%n 

)
)
) 

pause
```

Which gives me an output like

Model1 - DE
Model1 - FR
Model1 - ES
Model2 - DE
Model2 - FI
Model2 - DK

and so on

Now, What I like to get is something like this :

Model1 - DE;FR;ES
Model2 - DE;FI;DK

and so on, so I could send my main folder as a single variable, and all subfolders for the main folder as a grouped variable to an application.

Hope I'm a bit clear here, I'm an absolute beginner to batch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be solved via this process:

```
1- For each one of the top-level folders:
2-   Initialize result with top-level folder name
3-   For each one of the subfolders below it
4-      If subfolder contains *.xml files: gather its name in result
5-   Show the result
```

This is the Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set catdir=%CD%\catalog\
cd %catdir%
for /D %%m in (*) do (
   set "result=%%m - "
   pushd "%%m"
   for /D %%n in (*) do (
      if exist "%%n\*.xml" (
         set "result=!result!%%n;"
      )
   )
   popd
   if not "!result!" == "%%m - " (
      echo !result:~0,-1!
   )
)
```

The `:~0,-1!` part in last echo command delete the semicolon of the last subfolder name.